# Java EE 7 with Spring MVC 3 in the web layer

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I need some input on using Java EE 7 with Spring MVC 3.
I like the way Spring MVC works but i prefer the Java EE stack for transactions and beans in general.

So my tought is to use Java EE 7 for business tier and Spring MVC 3 for presentation. Since im fairly new to Spring MVC I guess this would meen that my Controller beans would call my EJB's and then return a view in the presentation layer, however, this feels like over doing it?

**The question**: Are there any major drawbacks with this setup? Pitfalls? Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Do you really have to use EJBs in 2013?

Comment: by mixing implementation containers (Spring MVC invoking EJBs) it can introduce "unnecessary" complexity.  Spring 3.2 supports JEE 7 patterns and processes quite well - and even beyond - so it may be worth reviewing why you can't do the Service Layer in Spring

Comment: @incomplete-co.de Im not using Spring in the service layer becuse i simply prefer Java EE 7

Comment: @adarshr it was more of an example, it could just as well be CDI or something else

Comment: @adarshr >`Do you really have to use EJBs in 2013?` - What's wrong with EJB? It's a very simple, yet lightweight technology in 2013 providing excellent support for transactions, pooling and security. You can even enrich them with CDI scopes where necessary and use CDI injection and producers if needed.